# Can't get the Last Insert UUID with PDO/PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo, postgresql-9.2

My primary key is a UUID. When I make a new user inset I need to get the Inset ID.

Have tried to get it like this:

```
$insert=$connection->prepare("INSERT INTO db.schema.users (blocked) VALUES (false)")->execute();

var_dump($connection->lastInsertId('schema.users') );
```

But get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42809]: Wrong object type: 7 ERROR:  \"users\" is not a sequence
```

---

This is my table structure:

[image]

---

Is it even possible to get the UUID like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [`RETURNING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/sql-insert.html) syntax:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO db.schema.users (blocked) VALUES (false) RETURNING usr_uuid");
$stmt->execute()

var_dump($stmt->fetchColumn());
```

Comment: Got this: `SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name: 7 ERROR:  schema \"users\" does not exist`

Comment: @Borsn Check my updated code. `lastInsertId` wont work in this case.

Comment: I get another error now: `Call to a member function fetchColumn() on boolean`. `$stmt` or `$insert` in my case is `bool(true)`.

Comment: lastInsertId only works if the primary key is set to auto-increment. Otherwise lastInsertId will return 0 for a successful insert and -1 if unsuccessful, e.g. duplicate entry, invalid syntax